# Relation based search with elasticsearch / kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, join, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm running a software where a client-application communicates with a backend-service. In order to be able to track what the client does I want to analyze my logs in the backend. Therefore I've setup an ELK stack in the backend.

Setup and application behaves as follows:

a) filebeat delivers logfiles to my logstash backend
b) backend logs

```
[00:00:00] <session-id> page a requested
[00:00:10] <session-id> page b requested
[00:00:20] <session-id> page c requested
```

c) on a certain (finishing) behavior of the user the backend logs

```
[00:01:00] <session-id> <action-token>
```

Now I want to be able to query all log entries (listed in b) which are related to  from c by the session-id.

From what I've read, joining queries is not possible in elasticsearch.

The documentation says one could denormalize the data. Since the action-token is given after the other logs were fed into elasticsearch I cannot enrich these events with the action-token. I need a way to do this when I receive the event in c. Is this the way to go? If so, how is this possible? If not, are there alternatives? I cannot imagine that this situation is so uncommon.

Best regards,
bk